# Produce a subset of atoms based on another subset

Tags: alloy

I have the following model:

```
sig A1 {
// ... 
}
sig A2 {
// ...
}

sig S {
    s_a1: one A1,
    s_a2: one A2
}
```

I'd like to "produce" a subset s1:S based on the elements of s0:S subject to the following constraints:

- s1 has the same number of atoms as s0
- those atoms s_valid in s0 that meet condition c1[s_valid.s_a1] must also be contained in s1
- for each of those atoms s_invalid in s0 that does not meet c1[s_invalid.s_a1] there must be an atom in s1 with the same s_a1 but a different s_a2 association

The aim is to simulate the modification of some of the items in a collection.
I've tried to solve this problem with comprehension expressions but I can't find the right means to express the change in the s_a2 association.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
-- s1 has the same number of atoms as s0
#s1 = #s2
-- those atoms s_valid in s0 that meet condition c1[s_valid.s_a1] must also be contained in s1
{x: s0 | c1[x.s_a1]} in s1
-- for each of those atoms s_invalid in s0 that does not meet c1[s_invalid.s_a1] there must be an atom in s1 with the same s_a1 but a different s_a2 association
all x: s0 | not c1[x.s_a1] implies some y: s1 | y.s_a1 = x.s_a1 and y.s_a2 != x.s_a2
```

Comment: A most helpful answer. I still have to work on it a bit, because my problem statement wasn't precise enough. By analogy, s0 and s1 are record sets, s0 contains some records with invalid field values and s1 is the corrected record set containing exactly the valid entries in s0 and the corrected versions of the invalid ones in s0. Anyhow, it's even more educative this way.

Comment: Studying Alloy is a wonderful journey. I find that it indeed often provokes fresh ideas and not just about software but also logic and modelling the physical world. Thank you, Professor.